# Find overriding methods for a specific method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there an opportunity in Eclipse to see if and when yes which classes overrides a method?

For example:

```
class A {
    void sayHello() {};
}


class B extens A {
}


class C extens A {
    void sayHello() { System.out.println("I am in class C"; }
}
```

So, when I open class `A` in the editor and the method `sayHello()` is highlighted, I want to find out that class `C` overrides it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Quick Type Hierarchy option (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to find the types implementing/overriding a method of a class and go into their implementation.

[image: Quick Type Hierarchy screenshot]

Find usage details here: [Viewing the type hierarchy](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-6.htm)

Comment: Alternatively, pressing `F4` should open type hierarchy, which is kind of similar.